# Integrate Rabbitmq With NiFi Instance Or How to consume a rabbitmq que from NiFi : Consume AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-nifi, amqp, messagebroker

How to subscribe a rabbitmq que from NiFi?
Is there any possible way to configure to integrate nifi with rabbitmq, in such a way that nifi can consume the data in which rabbitmq publishes.

When tries to connects with amqp getting connection errors as in the image below.

[image]

Thanks in advance.